# Spotify/pandora timer

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s, music, pandora

Is there an app that is preferrably free that will shut off (not just mute the phone as I don't want Pandora sucking bandwitdh all night) that will shut off Pandora or spotify after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not free, but you probably can use [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)to do this.   I use Pocket Casts to listen to podcasts, and have a Tasker profile set up:

3 Contexts: Shake left-right; app Pocket Cast running; Not Docked Car

2 Tasks: Notify (turn LED on, title "Sleep"); Wait 12 minutes, then Pause *Simulate Media Button*, then Notify Cancel title "Sleep"

Net effect is that I can shake the phone left then right, and Pocket Cast will behave as if the Pause button on a headset were pushed 12 minutes later.   I used the notification LED so I could tell whether Sleep had been activated when the screen is off.

I'm guessing Pandora would observe the headphone pause function; if it does, this profile should work for you.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like a Tasker shill because about half of my answers here mention it, but it really is like a Swiss Army Knife for personalization of my phone.

Comment: I would add that Tasker's user interface is a little on the opaque side, but once you get the hang of it, you can do all sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes tasker is the key but I prefer [llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) because its free and its awesome. Actually its location based profile app but it can be used for your condition.

There is a condition called "time between", add that condition and choose "kill application" for its action. Add your desired time and application